# Highcharts. How to set interval for PlotBand?

Tags: highcharts

I have multiseries spline chart. All series has own plotBand.
Is it possible to limit the plotBand interval by the length of the series?

Example, edited image:
[image]

plotLines can't help too:

```
plotLines: [{
            value: 12345,
            width: 10
        }]

plotBands: [{
            from: 30,
            to: 45
        }],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r00tGER/1nuw4fqs/

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, but you can use [Renderer.rect](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.rect) to add custom shape

```
chart.renderer.rect(100, 100, 100, 100, 5)
        .attr({
            'stroke-width': 2,
            stroke: 'red',
            fill: 'yellow',
            zIndex: 3
        })
        .add();
```

Second solution is using [annotation](https://github.com/blacklabel/annotations) which allows to add rectangles.

Comment: Use load / redraw events in chart object and then destroy and create new shape each time.

Comment: seems much easier, and more dynamic, to use either an area range or polygon series to draw the bands.

Comment: Makes sense, we have a few solutions for this case.

Answer (score 2):

Add one more range-type series as plot for every series.

```
series: [
    {
        name: 'as Plot',
        type: 'areasplinerange',
        data: [
            [1434620400000, 58.0, 68.0], [1434620640000, 58.0, 68.0]
         ],
        zIndex: 0
    }
    ]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r00tGER/ueqht2eL/